# How to add html in Ext.msg.confirm

Tags: extjs4

How to add html in `Ext.msg.confirm` using extjs?
I have tried in this manner

```
var messageVal = 'Are you sure you want to permanently delete the selected Names "abcd11, abcdefg_test_maxim_char0, abcdefg_test_maxim_char1, abcdefg_test_maxim_char2, abcdefg_test_maxim_char3, abcdefg_test_maxim_char4, abcdefg_test_maxim_char5, abcdefg_test_maxim_char6, abcdefg_test_maxim_char7, abcdefg_test_maxim_char8, abcdefg_test_maxim_char9, abcdefg_test_maxim_chars0, abcdefg_test_maxim_chars1, abcdefg_test_maxim_chars2, abcdefg_test_maxim_chars3, abcdefg_test_maxim_chars4, abcdefg_test_maxim_chars5, abcdefg_test_maxim_chars6, abcdefg_test_maxim_chars7, abcdefg_test_maxim_chars8, abcdefg_test_maxim_chars9, abcdefg_test_maxim_chars_0, abcdefg_test_maxim_chars_1, abcdefg_test_maxim_chars_2, abcdefg_test_maxim_chars_3, abcdefg_test_maxim_chars_4, abcdefg_test_maxim_chars_5, abcdefg_test_maxim_chars_6, abcdefg_test_maxim_chars_7, abcdefg_test_maxim_chars_8, abcdefg_test_maxim_chars_9, abcdefg_test_max_chars_2, abcdefg_test_maxim_char0, abcdefg_test_maxim_char250, abcdefg_test_maxim_char260, abcdefg_test_maxim_char270, abcdefg_test_maxim_char0, abcdefg_test_maxim_char50, abcdefg_test_maxim_char60, abcdefg_test_maxim_char10, abcdefg_test_maxim_char20, abcdefg_test_maxim_char30, abcdefg_test_maxim_char40, abcdefg_test_maxim_char70, abcdefg_test_maxim_char80, abcdefg_test_maxim_char90, abcdefg_test_maxim_char100, abcdefg_test_maxim_char110, abcdefg_test_maxim_char120, abcdefg_test_maxim_char130, abcdefg_test_maxim_char140, abcdefg_test_maxim_char150, abcdefg_test_maxim_char160, abcdefg_test_maxim_char170, abcdefg_test_maxim_char180, abcdefg_test_maxim_char190, abcdefg_test_maxim_char200, abcdefg_test_maxim_char210, abcdefg_test_maxim_char220, abcdefg_test_maxim_char230, abcdefg_test_maxim_char240, abcdefg_test_maxim_char250, abcdefg_test_maxim_char290, abcdefg_test_maxim_char300, abcdefg_test_maxim_char310, abcdefg_test_maxim_char320, abcdefg_test_maxim_char330, abcdefg_test_maxim_char340, abcdefg_test_maxim_char350, abcdefg_test_maxim_char360, abcdefg_test_maxim_char370, abcdefg_test_maxim_char380, abcdefg_test_maxim_char390, abcdefg_test_maxim_char400"?';


Ext.MessageBox.confirm({
  title: 'Delete Names',
  msg: messageVal,
  buttons: Ext.Msg.YESNO,
});
```

But msg is not getting viewed.

Answer (score 1):

Javascript simply doesn't support modal operation,you have to use callback, Try this code

```
var messageVal = 'Are you sure you want to permanently delete the selected Names "abcd11, abcdefg_test_maxim_char0, abcdefg_test_maxim_char1, abcdefg_test_maxim_char2, abcdefg_test_maxim_char3, abcdefg_test_maxim_char4, abcdefg_test_maxim_char5, abcdefg_test_maxim_char6, abcdefg_test_maxim_char7, abcdefg_test_maxim_char8, abcdefg_test_maxim_char9, abcdefg_test_maxim_chars0, abcdefg_test_maxim_chars1, abcdefg_test_maxim_chars2, abcdefg_test_maxim_chars3, abcdefg_test_maxim_chars4, abcdefg_test_maxim_chars5, abcdefg_test_maxim_chars6, abcdefg_test_maxim_chars7, abcdefg_test_maxim_chars8, abcdefg_test_maxim_chars9, abcdefg_test_maxim_chars_0, abcdefg_test_maxim_chars_1, abcdefg_test_maxim_chars_2, abcdefg_test_maxim_chars_3, abcdefg_test_maxim_chars_4, abcdefg_test_maxim_chars_5, abcdefg_test_maxim_chars_6, abcdefg_test_maxim_chars_7, abcdefg_test_maxim_chars_8, abcdefg_test_maxim_chars_9, abcdefg_test_max_chars_2, abcdefg_test_maxim_char0, abcdefg_test_maxim_char250, abcdefg_test_maxim_char260, abcdefg_test_maxim_char270, abcdefg_test_maxim_char0, abcdefg_test_maxim_char50, abcdefg_test_maxim_char60, abcdefg_test_maxim_char10, abcdefg_test_maxim_char20, abcdefg_test_maxim_char30, abcdefg_test_maxim_char40, abcdefg_test_maxim_char70, abcdefg_test_maxim_char80, abcdefg_test_maxim_char90, abcdefg_test_maxim_char100, abcdefg_test_maxim_char110, abcdefg_test_maxim_char120, abcdefg_test_maxim_char130, abcdefg_test_maxim_char140, abcdefg_test_maxim_char150, abcdefg_test_maxim_char160, abcdefg_test_maxim_char170, abcdefg_test_maxim_char180, abcdefg_test_maxim_char190, abcdefg_test_maxim_char200, abcdefg_test_maxim_char210, abcdefg_test_maxim_char220, abcdefg_test_maxim_char230, abcdefg_test_maxim_char240, abcdefg_test_maxim_char250, abcdefg_test_maxim_char290, abcdefg_test_maxim_char300, abcdefg_test_maxim_char310, abcdefg_test_maxim_char320, abcdefg_test_maxim_char330, abcdefg_test_maxim_char340, abcdefg_test_maxim_char350, abcdefg_test_maxim_char360, abcdefg_test_maxim_char370, abcdefg_test_maxim_char380, abcdefg_test_maxim_char390, abcdefg_test_maxim_char400"?';
title: 'Delete Names',
Ext.Msg.confirm('title', messageVal, function(btn, text){
    if (btn == 'ok'){
        // add here what you need to do.

    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how you  have to give

```
   var messageVal = 'Are you sure you want to permanently delete the selected Names "abcd11, abcdefg_test_maxim_char0, abcdefg_test_maxim_char1, abcdefg_test_maxim_char2, abcdefg_test_maxim_char3, abcdefg_test_maxim_char4, abcdefg_test_maxim_char5, abcdefg_test_maxim_char6, abcdefg_test_maxim_char7, abcdefg_test_maxim_char8, abcdefg_test_maxim_char9, abcdefg_test_maxim_chars0, abcdefg_test_maxim_chars1, abcdefg_test_maxim_chars2, abcdefg_test_maxim_chars3, abcdefg_test_maxim_chars4, abcdefg_test_maxim_chars5, abcdefg_test_maxim_chars6, abcdefg_test_maxim_chars7, abcdefg_test_maxim_chars8, abcdefg_test_maxim_chars9, abcdefg_test_maxim_chars_0, abcdefg_test_maxim_chars_1, abcdefg_test_maxim_chars_2, abcdefg_test_maxim_chars_3, abcdefg_test_maxim_chars_4, abcdefg_test_maxim_chars_5, abcdefg_test_maxim_chars_6, abcdefg_test_maxim_chars_7, abcdefg_test_maxim_chars_8, abcdefg_test_maxim_chars_9, abcdefg_test_max_chars_2, abcdefg_test_maxim_char0, abcdefg_test_maxim_char250, abcdefg_test_maxim_char260, abcdefg_test_maxim_char270, abcdefg_test_maxim_char0, abcdefg_test_maxim_char50, abcdefg_test_maxim_char60, abcdefg_test_maxim_char10, abcdefg_test_maxim_char20, abcdefg_test_maxim_char30, abcdefg_test_maxim_char40, abcdefg_test_maxim_char70, abcdefg_test_maxim_char80, abcdefg_test_maxim_char90, abcdefg_test_maxim_char100, abcdefg_test_maxim_char110, abcdefg_test_maxim_char120, abcdefg_test_maxim_char130, abcdefg_test_maxim_char140, abcdefg_test_maxim_char150, abcdefg_test_maxim_char160, abcdefg_test_maxim_char170, abcdefg_test_maxim_char180, abcdefg_test_maxim_char190, abcdefg_test_maxim_char200, abcdefg_test_maxim_char210, abcdefg_test_maxim_char220, abcdefg_test_maxim_char230, abcdefg_test_maxim_char240, abcdefg_test_maxim_char250, abcdefg_test_maxim_char290, abcdefg_test_maxim_char300, abcdefg_test_maxim_char310, abcdefg_test_maxim_char320, abcdefg_test_maxim_char330, abcdefg_test_maxim_char340, abcdefg_test_maxim_char350, abcdefg_test_maxim_char360, abcdefg_test_maxim_char370, abcdefg_test_maxim_char380, abcdefg_test_maxim_char390, abcdefg_test_maxim_char400"?';

Ext.MessageBox.confirm('Delete Names', messageVal, function(btn){
    if(btn === 'yes'){
        //necessary actions
    }
});
```

Here is the fiddle link 
https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/2gps

Answer (score 0):

[`Ext.MessageBox.confirm`](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.1.1/#!/api/Ext.window.MessageBox-method-confirm) accept parameters in following format

```
confirm( title, msg, [fn], [scope] )
```

- **title : String**

  The title bar text
- **msg : String**

The message box body text

- **fn : Function (optional)**

The callback function invoked after the message box is closed. See show method for details.

- **scope : Object (optional)**

The scope (this reference) in which the callback is executed.

You can check with following working [Fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/2gpt).